# String concatenation in C# with DateTime objects: why is my code legal?

Tags: c#, concatenation

In some C# code I'm working on, a `DateTime` object (`dt`) is concatenated with two strings:

```
string test = "This is a test " + dt + "...Why does this work?"
```

This doesn't raise a compile error and is working just fine. My question: why is this legal? Is this specific only to `DateTime` objects, or to any objects overriding the `ToString()` method?

Comment: All objects have `ToString()` because it is defined on `Object` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx

Comment: Because **usually** `string + anything` [is equal to](http://dotnetfiddle.net/VSUGjL) `string + anything.ToString()`

Comment: @abatishchev No, it's not.  The two are different if `anything` is `null`.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Which is "closed as not a real question"?

Comment: @Servy: Yes, thank your for clarification. I meant anything is something not null. Null is nothing is such notation :)

Comment: @CodeCaster - yeah that question has Slaks and Skeet with the snazzy answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an implicit type conversion of a parameter that is performed because of the + operator.

It is talked about in the specification here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691375%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I was hoping for.

Answer (score 5):

It compiles because the C# specifications state that there is an overload of the `+` operator with the following signature:

```
operator + (string str, object obj)
```

You are providing a `string` and an expression that is implicitly convertable to `object`, so this operator and no others matches your arguments, and it compiles.

Internally this operator's implementation will call `string.Concat`, which will convert the object into a string using its `ToString` method (assuming it is not null) and then concat the strings as strings.